# huggingface return probability and class label Trainer.predict

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Is there any way to return probabilities and actual class using `Trainer.predict` ?

I checked the documentation at this [page](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer) but couldn't figure out. As of now it seems to be returning logits

Obviously both probabilities and actual class could be computed using additional coding but wondering if there is any prebuilt method to do the same

my current output as below

```
new_predictions=trainer.predict(dataset_for_future_predicition_after_tokenizer)

new_predictions


PredictionOutput(predictions=array([[-0.43005577,  3.646306  , -0.8073783 , -1.0651836 , -1.3480505 ,
        -1.108013  ],
       [ 3.5415223 , -0.8513837 , -1.8553216 , -0.18011567, -0.35627165,
        -1.8364134 ],
       [-1.0167522 , -0.8911268 , -1.7115675 ,  0.01204597,  1.7177908 ,
         1.0401527 ],
       [-0.82407415, -0.46043932, -1.089274  ,  2.6252217 ,  0.33935028,
        -1.3623345 ]], dtype=float32), label_ids=None, metrics={'test_runtime': 0.0182, 'test_samples_per_second': 219.931, 'test_steps_per_second': 54.983})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned, `Trainer.predict` returns the output of the model prediction, which are the logits.

If you want to get the different labels and scores for each class, I recommend you to use the corresponding [`pipeline`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.2/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.pipeline) for your model depending on the task (TextClassification, TokenClassification, etc). This `pipeline` has a `return_all_scores` parameter on its `__call__` method that allows you to get all scores for each label on a prediction.

Here's an example:

```py
from transformers import TextClassificationPipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

MODEL_NAME = "..."
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

pipe = TextClassificationPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
prediction = pipe("The text to predict", return_all_scores=True)
```

This is an example of how this `prediction` variable will look like:

```
[{label: 'LABEL1', score: 0.80}, {label: 'LABEL2', score: 0.15}, {label: 'LABEL3', score: 0.05}]
```

The label names can be set on the model's `config.json` file or when creating the model (before training it) by defining `id2label` and `label2id` model parameters:

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    MODEL_NAME,
    num_labels=num_labels,
    label2id={"Greeting": 0, "Help": 1, "Farewell": 2},
    id2label={0: "Greeting", 1: "Help", 2: "Farewell"},
)
```

Comment: thanks. I liked your suggestion - `when creating the model (before training it) by defining id2label and label2id model parameters:.` do you have an example of `id2label` and `label2id`?

Comment: @user2543622 I updated my answer with an example

Comment: this helped me get the scores for all classes in text classification `pipeline("text-classification"); pipe('this is a test', top_k=None)`. Also note `return_all_scores` is deprecated